# ArgumentException when converting JSON to Model using Newtonsoft in ASP.Net Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft in my ASP.Net Core web app and web API but I am getting a

> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to TCGInfo.WebUI.Models.TCGModel.

Here is my code:

Create JSON:

```
    public async Task<string> GetTCGList()
    {
        var TCGList = await _manageCardHelper.GetTCGList();
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(TCGList);
        return json;
    }
```

Read JSON:

```
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("GetTCGList");

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TCGModel>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

        }
```

Model:

```
public class TCGModel
{
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the route you're fetching ("GetTCG**List**"), I'm assuming you're actually get an array of models back, not just one. You need to tell `DeserializeObject` that:

```
jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TCGModel>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code above, all I can say is `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` should take a list of TCFModel instead of the TCFModel. The following line of code should work.

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TCGModel>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Comment: This gives me the same error but instead just TCGModel it is List of TCGMode. But at this point I have abandoned the API and moved on to other methods. It seems ASP.Net Core is not ready for API usage.